# I want to return "Customer Name" from "Customer Table" where "Active Customer ID" on my form matches "Customer ID" in "Customer Table"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

`Table: Case_Info` holds the `Customer Reference` value that the case is assigned to, which is looked up from the Table: `Client_List`.
`Table: Client_List` has a list of `Customer References`, along with all the customer information, including `[fName]`.
The user interacts with a form called the `Portal` which has a SubForm feed called `Case - View`, and another SubForm within that called `Case View - Case Info`.

I want the `fName` to be shown in the `Case - View` depending on the active `Case` record the user is looking at, matching via the `Customer ID`.

I'm trying to use `DLookUp`, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong as I'm trying to get the information from a combo box which feeds from a query.

This is returning `#Name?` :
`=DLookUp("[fName]","[Client_List]","Forms![Case View]![cmbCustRef] = '" & [Client_List]![ClientID] & "'")`

[image: See image]

Comment: See how to [reference controls in subforms](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm). Try: `DLookUp("[fName]","[Client_List]","ClientID=" & Forms!Portal![Case View].Form![cmbCustRef])`.

Comment: Hey, I'll test this later on and let you know. Many thanks.

Comment: Hey, so I've been meddling with this. Your suggestion had the same problem unfortunately. I tried taking out the entry after "ClientID=" and replaced it with a valid, literal query (ie, an entry) - to which it worked. However that's no good, so I followed the Reference controls in subforms guide and came up with this: **=DLookUp("[fName]","[Client_List]",ClientID='" & [Me].Parent![cmbCustRef].Text & "'")**. The new error however is "The express you entered has an invalid string. A string can be up to 2048 characters long, including opening and closing quotation marks."

Comment: Rookie mistake; repaired, but same #Name? error. **=DLookUp("[fName]","[Client_List]","ClientID = '" & Me.Parent![cmbCustRef].Text & "'")**

Comment: Also same #Name? error. **=DLookUp("[fName]","[Client_List]","ClientID = '" & [Forms]![Case View]![cmbCustRef].[Text] & "'")**